# Different roles have different cooldowns discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

At the moment i have this:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.has_role(803952153496256512):
        @commands.cooldown(3, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    elif ctx.message.author.has_role(803952219694432326 ):
        @commands.cooldown(5, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    elif ctx.message.author.has_role(803952282198212668 ):
        @commands.cooldown(7, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    else:
        return
```

I want it so if the user has a certain role the cooldown on the command would be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been the best with configuring cooldowns, but what I can help you with is your role detection. In order to tell if a member has a role, we're going to need a few things; the member object and the role id. It seems that you have all of those in your command context, so we should be good to write some code. I'd just reform your code to something more like this.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952153496256512)]):
        pass
    elif any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952219694432326)]):
        pass
    elif any([discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id = 803952282198212668)]):
        pass
```